# Problems loading data into combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

```
public void muestraRegistro(JTextField t1 ,JTextField t2 , JTextField t3 , JTextField t4 , JTextField t5,JTextField t6 , JComboBox cmb) {
    try {

        int row = ProductoGUI.tblDetalle.getSelectedRow();  
        String muestra = ProductoGUI.tblDetalle.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        //String muestra = ProductoGUI.tblDetalle.getValueAt(ProductoGUI.tblDetalle.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
        rs = cargaRegistro();
        while (rs.next()) {                 
                t1.setText(rs.getString(1));
                t2.setText(rs.getString(2));                                     
                cmb.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(3));
                System.out.print(cmb);
                t3.setText(rs.getString(4));
                t4.setText(rs.getString(5));
                t5.setText(rs.getString(6));
                t6.setText(rs.getString(7));

            habilitaTexto(false, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
        }
    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {             
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        Logger.getLogger(ProductoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I have the code, but I have trouble throws me the following message when loading the data from the combobox jtable

```
javax.swing.JComboBox[,113,91,200x18,layout=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI$3,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=1]javax.swing.JComboBox[,113,91,200x18,layout=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI$3,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=1]javax.swing.JComboBox[,113,91,200x18,layout=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI$3,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=1]
```

Comment: Explain your code please. What is `habilitaTexto` for one thing? Why are you setting JTextFields in a loop when only the last values will show the way you're doing it? Why are you passing JTextFields repeatedly into it? Why always the exact same JTextFields?

Comment: And you're seeing the `toString()` returned from a JCombBox. I'm guessing that you're calling `System.out.println(cmb);` or something similar to that, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: habilitaTexto is a method that disables the JTextField, and put the system.out.printl(cmb) to know why not fill me with the data the JComboBox and showed me the error stated in the question

Comment: Again, if you need our help, please put in just a little more effort and improve your question by explaining more of what you're trying to do. I see you using the ResultSet from a database, I see you rapidly filling JTextfields and then replacing them with other data too quickly before then intermediate data can show, but I have no idea what you're trying to do. More please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a jtable in which double click and called the muestraRegistro method which fills me each JTextField with the information of jtable, but the problem is when I try to fill the JComboBox, throws me the message that is at the end of the question,

Comment: That message is worthless since all it gives us is the default `toString()` from a JComboBox. Don't print the combobox since it's not going to give you information of use. If you want to see what it holds, then loop through its model and print out the contents.

Comment: Maybe it is better to print rs.getString(3) and cmb.getSelectedIndex(). What is the combo box model used to initialize `cmb`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score -1):

This simple example shows a combo box with a combo box model containing three strings. The `println` prints the string `cmb.getSelectedIndex(): 1` on my laptop (which corresponds to the second string in the model).

```
final JComboBox<String> cmb = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"123", "456", "789"});
cmb.setSelectedItem("456");
System.out.println("cmb.getSelectedIndex(): " + cmb.getSelectedIndex());
```